# NodeJS: how to read (at most) the first N bytes from a file?

Tags: node.js, file

In NodeJS, what is a concise, robust, and elegant way to read at most the first N bytes from a file?

- If there's less data then I don't want an error to be thrown.
- If there's more data then I don't want that to be read into memory.

Ideally without installing external packages. Maybe involving async iterators which seem to be new (non-experimental) since NodeJS 12?

Bonus: how do I read the first N *characters*, providing a specific codec (such as `utf-8`)?

Edit: based on my Internet research the answer to this indeed rather basic question is far from obvious, which is why I ask. I know how to do this in other language environments, and I am new to the NodeJS ecosystem.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6805

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/nodejs/readable-stream/issues/403

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been using the following approach for a while now in NodeJS 12 (with TypeScript):

```js
async function readFirstNBytes(path: fs.PathLike, n: number): Promise<Buffer> {
  const chunks = [];
  for await (let chunk of fs.createReadStream(path, { start: 0, end: n-1 })) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  }
  return Buffer.concat(chunks);
}
```

Comment: I think this will end up reading the entire file.

Comment: @Mythos why do you think so? The `end` parameter set to `n` should do it. Here is how it's documented: "options can include `start` and `end` values to read a range of bytes from the file instead of the entire file" -- https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v17.x/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatereadstreamoptions

Comment: You are right, for some reason I assumed `end` is relative to `start` as is the case with most stream reading/buffer reading implementations in most languages/frameworks (but then I guess the param is labelled `length` or `n`), The last example in the doc clears this up.

Comment: I would add a try/finally to close the stream

Comment: Be aware that `end` is inclusive, so `{ start: 0, end: n }` results in the first `n+1` bytes being read, not just the first `n` bytes. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/fs.html#fscreatereadstreampath-options

Comment: Oh! Thank you MDMower, I have adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to work with [readable streams](http://createReadStream) and [read](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size) event.

Attach a handler and keep checking the `chunk.length` compared to your accumulated read to determine if you should continue.

Will read the max that is stipulated, or the minimum considering the file length.

Demo to get you thinking:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

peek(path.resolve('./random/stream.js'), 100, 100)
    .then(result => {
        console.info(result.length);
    });

function peek(filePath, size, max, encoding) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {
            encoding: encoding || 'utf8'
        });

        let length = 0;
        let content = '';
        stream.on('readable', () => {
            let chunk;
            while (length < max && (chunk = stream.read(size)) !== null) {
                length += chunk.length;
                content += chunk.toString();

                if ((length + size) >= max) {
                    size = max - length;
                }
            }

            return resolve({
                length: length,
                content: content
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking this through! I have not yet had the time to parse the response in detail, and to compare it with other potential approaches, but will get back to it!