# NodeJS: How to get first N bytes of a remote text file into string

Tags: node.js

I would like to read first 1024 bytes of remote RSS file. I do not want to read a whole file that can be huge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS: how to read (at most) the first N bytes from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985876/nodejs-how-to-read-at-most-the-first-n-bytes-from-a-file)

Comment: @DanielTran My question is about a remote link/file